# Export individual user data in user id feature of analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the user id feature in analyitcs and I am also getting the tracking of user activities. Bt I am unable to find any option to export the report for individual user id. Is there any way to export the report or get the data by GAPI

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

> After processing, session data for which userId was set is available
>   for User ID-enabled views (profiles) in Cross-Device reports. Although
>   the session data is available via the Core Reporting API, the userId
>   field is not available as a dimension in reports and can not be
>   exported from Analytics.

Please refer to [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660#reporting) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to retrieve and export data from one specific user, you can do so using Google's User Activity Reporting API. You can see how to do so here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting . If you would like to retrieve your user IDs from Google's Core Reporting API, you can do so by using a custom dimension that has its value set to your user IDs. You would then include "name":"ga:dimension4" (4 is the custom dimension index, just an example) within the dimensions section of the request body for that API.